# Create a sticky navigation header using jquery waypoints works with mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation, sticky, jquery-waypoints

I'm using this jquery sticky navigation

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/

But it doesn't work in mobile mostly the ipad. After the 1st time the nav doesn't go back to the navigation location and the sticky class doesn't go away. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you actually look at their example page in ipad it deos the same thing. http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

This is due to the (older) ipads not supporting position: fixed correctly. Here is a method I have used to implement on older ipads etc: http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED

updated:
Developer actually explains this on github - https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/issues/51